# Is there a way to convert a char to its ASCII value in assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm

I need to obtain the ASCII value of a char in arm assembly, preferably in hexadecimal format.
For example, if the char is 'a', I need my program to output 0x61.
The closest thing I've found is typecasting in C, where

```
int x = 'a';
```

seems to do the trick. Is there anything similar in arm?
Thanks

Comment: A character is its ASCII code.  This is the case in C as it is the case in assembly.  There is no need to obtain the ASCII code of a character because that's what the character is.

Comment: There's no typecast occurring here. `'a' ` is already an int in C

Comment: Most assemblers support ASCII character literals like `mov r0, #'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most assemblers support ASCII character literals like `mov r0, #'a'`

Otherwise just look up the integer value of the ASCII code.  http://www.asciitable.com/

Once you have a binary integer in a register, print it in hex or decimal the same way as any other integer, e.g. `printf` or split it up into 4-bit nibbles and add `'0'` or `'A'` to each digit.